# using Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment not functioning in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fragment, deprecated

I am trying to get FragmentTransation and FragmentManager to work in C# using Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment however the namespace is greyed out and VS says 'Using directive is unnecessary'. I have installed the Xamarin Android Support V4 NuGet Package, cleaned and rebuilt my project, installed Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, none have worked. Please help me as to why these are still being deemed obsolete in VS even though I have included this library.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using System;

namespace LoginSystem
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        private Button mBtnSignUp;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            mBtnSignUp = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignUp);

            mBtnSignUp.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                //DEPRECATION HERE
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                dialog_SignUp signUpDialog = new dialog_SignUp();
                signUpDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
            };
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the nuget package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 v28.0.0.3?

If you have it, you have to use the SupportFragmentManager instead of the FragmentManager, and that will resolve your problem.

Take alook at this:
[image]

Comment: Yes I have that exact package. Unfortunately FragmentTransaction still is deprecated and there doesn't seem to exist a SupportFragmentTransaction either.. when I change FragmentTransaction to var, the .Show() stops working

Comment: Hi, It is working here without any problem. The SupportFragmentManager is part of the context if you inherit from AppCompatActivity.
It appears to be a misconfiguration, so if I was you; I'll delete the .vs folder, along with bin and obj folders, and also will clear the packages cache (I'm assuming you know how to do it). Then I will cross my fingers and restart the VS as admin and try to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SupportFragmentManager` and fully qualify `FragmentTransaction` since that class exists in two namespaces.

`Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you use FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction, the namespace are **Android.App.FragmentManager** and **Android.App.FragmentTransation**, then signUpDialog is the namespace:**Android.app.fragment**, but you can take a look the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment),it is deprecated in Android Pie / API Level 28.

So you can use Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, firstly, you need to install **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** by Nuget package firstly.

Then use FrameLayout to contains **Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment**

```
 Fragment1 dialog = new Fragment1();
 Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
 ft.Replace(Resource.Id.myFrameLayout, dialog).Commit();
```

I do one sample about this two ways, you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/fragment